# How can I read a CSV file with UTF-8 code page in SQL bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8

I have a Persian CSV file and I need to read that with SQL bulk into the SQL server:

I wrote this bulk:

```
BULK INSERT TEMP
FROM 'D:\t1.csv'
WITH(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
CODEPAGE = '1256'
);
```

but that can not read UTF-8 encoding and read `ی` character as `?` character.

How can I write that?

Comment: For Hebrew CODEPAGE = '65001' worked, SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1):

**1**. go to the [`BULK INSERT` documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

**2.** find the section on the `CODEPAGE`

**3.** see the note that says:
*SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).*

**4.** Research further and find the [Use Unicode Character Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx) and see if that helps

Comment: The documentation currently states "** Important ** Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)."

Comment: @user1069816: true - but in August 2015, when I wrote this answer, there was no SQL Server 2016 yet ..... and as far as I know, UTF-8 support was really only added in earnest in SQL Server **2019** just recently

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still there in SQL server 2017, see [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35245150-bulk-insert-does-not-work-utf-8-support-enabled-fo) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/109417/sql-server-2008-does-not-support-code-page-65001-for-utf8-encoding-when-importin).

If your import is just an occasional exercise, i.e. if it's OK to import not using a script at all, what worked for me is simply importing the csv using Tasks -> Import -> Flat file.

I'm adding this here because this page is high up when you Google 'SQL Server does not support code page 65001'. Hope it helps some.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documenation @marc_s linked to, and found the usage of `DATAFILETYPE = widechar`.
I then went ahead and tried it with my UTF-8 csv file, but it didn't work, giving me the error:

> [...] the data file does not have a Unicode signature

I then **re-saved** my csv file with [Notepad's Unicode format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951826/3002584), retried the import, and voila, success.

- Make sure all commas and line-breaks are escaped ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68299056/3002584) how to save a valid csv).

My full script (I'm using SQL Server 2017):

```
BULK INSERT [my_table]
FROM 'C:\path\to\file.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIRSTROW = 2,           -- if you have a title row, the first data row is 2nd
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    KEEPIDENTITY,           -- remove it if you don't want identity to be kept
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   
    DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar', 
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\path\to\file_err.txt',
    KEEPNULLS,
    TABLOCK
)
```

Notes:

- Make sure your date fields are in valid sql format.
- Regarding `KEEPNULS`, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581814/insert-a-empty-string-on-sql-server-with-bulk-insert) (e.g, if you have `NULL`s in your file, replace them with an empty string).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the now deprecated or obsolete earlier answers by others I want to point out that a of today in May 2022, **with Release Version 15.0.2080.9 (SQL Server 2019), this works flawlessly for UTF-8.**

- Create a UTF-8 encoded file (I use with BOM)

then

```
BULK INSERT #tempTable1
FROM 'C:\....\file.csv' WITH (
CODEPAGE = '65001',
FIRSTROW = 2, --skip the first line
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO
```

works flawlessly for me, with many french and other characters.