# Bulk insert ,double Fieldterminator at the last column issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

when I insert from a csv with bulk, the last column has FIELDTERMINATOR twice when it should be null, in the csv that field is empty.

`

```
   BULK INSERT my_table FROM 'path'
   WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FIRSTROW = 2
         )
```

`

the way that the last column is null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a empty string on SQL Server with BULK INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581814/insert-a-empty-string-on-sql-server-with-bulk-insert)

Comment: no, I have other columns that are empty and when I insert them automatically they are placed as null, except the last one which places a double comma.

Comment: Sounds like your CSV file has more columns than the destination table. e.g.: for a table with 3 columns, all text from column 3 and beyond in the CSV file will get read into the third column of the table. On a line-by-line basis. Excel is notorious for causing this - deleting data in a column still writes out blank columns (and so field delimiter characters) to the CSV file.

Comment: The csv I'm working with has data removed from the last column in excel, is there a way to correct this without having to modify the csv directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSV file to see if it contains extra columns and/or delimiter characters on the affected lines.

Consider the following CSV example:

```
Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,
1,2,,
1,2,3
1,2,3,
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,
```

When reading it into a table with the following SQL code:

```sql
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists my_table;
go
create table my_table (
    [First] varchar(10),
    [Second] varchar(10),
    [Third] varchar(10)
);
go
BULK INSERT my_table FROM 'C:\Temp\example.csv' WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2
);
select * from my_table;
go
```

It will yield the following imported results:

| First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | , |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3, |
| 1 | 2 | 3,4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3,4, |
| 1 | 2 | 3,4,5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3,4,5, |